# Access extension properties via Microsoft Graph SDK for Java

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a custom user property implemented via [the Extension Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0) on my directory. The property is visible in the graph explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6dc2cecc-a3dd-4c18-ba7a-38b70db82e95?$select=extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour
```

returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour)/$entity",
    "extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour": "foooooo"
}
```

I can also see it in the raw response in the User object returned by `com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.User#getRawObject` when using MS Graph Java SDK, but the User class doesn't seem to have any API for accessing this kind of properties. Best I can do is manipulating the raw response. Is there any better way of accessing extension properties without touching the raw response?

Comment: Did you check if you can get the data from these properity? As the document said that the response should be a `extensionProperty`
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPl6b.png

Comment: Maybe [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request-2)?

Comment: @TinyWang it's null, even tough I use call `.expand("extensions")` when building the request. This field might be for open or schema extensions, but not extension properties.

Comment: also those docs don't have any info on getting extension properties.

Comment: I tested in my side and got a weird result. In my opinion, code `User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().select("extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour").get();` should have the same result as a request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour`, but they share different result in fact. I can get value of the extension_xx_xx claim from http request, but I can't get that property in the `User` entity in the code. I both test with v1.0 and beta version in java code, but no luck. I think it's due to the SDK itself.

Answer (score 0):

Extension properties can be accessed by ExtensionPropertyCollectionPage class

If you are using User Class, you can try with below code inside the User Class:

```
final User user = graphClient.me()
    .buildRequest()
    .select("extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour")
    .get();
```

Comment: This collection class doesn't seem to be accessible via the User class

Comment: are you able to access this property from graph API using select?

Answer (score 0):

The `User` entity really doesn't contain the extension property. Then I try to find answer from the c# SDK, as I tested by c# SDK, I can get the extension claim from the `User.Result.AdditionalData`, so I came back to Java SDK and I found the property `additionalDataManager`, then I test it and get the result.

```
User user = graphClient.users("198a7xxxxx19ce1c").buildRequest().get();
String res = user.additionalDataManager().get("extension_3d3xxxxe8707e_tiny_custom_prop").toString();
```

[image]

=================================Update=================================

It's ok for me to get it

```
UserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
                .buildRequest().select("extension_3d35xxx7e_tiny_custom_prop")
                .get();
        String temp = users.getCurrentPage().get(1).additionalDataManager().get("extension_3d35xxx07e_tiny_custom_prop").toString();
```

And if you find it not working for you, maybe you can try to [use beta version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk) for calling the api.

```
    <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>sonatype-snapshot</id>
              <name>Sonatype Snapshot</name>
              <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    
    <dependency>
              <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
              <artifactId>microsoft-graph-beta</artifactId>
              <version>0.33.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>[1.3,)</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. `user.additionalDataManager()` indeed returns the property when querying a specific user. Though if you're trying to get a collection of users, `additionalDataManager` is empty for all of them, i.e. `graphClient.users().buildRequest().select("extension_8655692d0a034443a9b32af6caa95f56_favColour").get().getCurrentPage().get(<idx>).additionalDataManager()` returns an empty manager.

Comment: @super.t I tested in my side and it worked for me, see my updates above to try my code or change the dependency.